# Atom download takes me to Github, doesn't download application

Tags: python, github, python3, atom-editor, python-gui

I'm attempting to install Atom on Mac, but when I click "download" on the [atom.io](https://atom.io/) site it takes me to Github. I have installed Atom on other devices, and I remember that this would normally just install the software. Does this also happen to anyone else? Are there any alternatives to obtain this software? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Mac version of Atom is not a direct executable file for download and install. If you go to the bottom of the Github page you can download atom-mac.zip by clicking on it. Unzip that and in there is Atom.app. After that, you can drag the app to your Applications folder and it is installed.
Check out the installation guide for how to install: https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-mac